# Why do I get "Attribute (class) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::RunnableClass'"?

Tags: perl, moose

I'm attempting to create a runnable Moose program following the example in the [MooseX::Runnable docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Runnable)):

```
package LaborData::Data::DBIxTest;
use Moose;
use Modern::Perl;
use LaborData::Data::Schema;
with 'DB', 'MooseX::Runnable';

sub run {
  my ($self, $name) = @_; 
  say $name;
}
```

But when I run

```
mx-run LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm hi
```

on the command line, I get this error:

```
Attribute (class) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::RunnableClass' with value "LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm" at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Moose/Util.pm line 49
    Moose::Util::throw_exception('ValidationFailedForTypeConstraint', 'type', 'MooseX::Types::TypeDecorator=HASH(0x38728e8)', 'value', 'LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm', 'attribute', 'Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x38bd4e8)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 1265
    Moose::Meta::Attribute::verify_against_type_constraint('Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x38bd4e8)', 'LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm', 'instance', 'MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::MxRun=HASH(0x38a13d8)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 1252
    Moose::Meta::Attribute::_coerce_and_verify('Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x38bd4e8)', 'LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm', 'MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::MxRun=HASH(0x38a13d8)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 511
    Moose::Meta::Attribute::initialize_instance_slot('Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x38bd4e8)', 'Moose::Meta::Instance=HASH(0x3881ad0)', 'MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::MxRun=HASH(0x38a13d8)', 'HASH(0x37fc528)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 524
    Class::MOP::Class::_construct_instance('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x3481260)', 'HASH(0x37fc528)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 494
    Class::MOP::Class::new_object('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x3481260)', 'HASH(0x37fc528)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 274
    Moose::Meta::Class::new_object('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x3481260)', 'HASH(0x37fc528)') called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Moose/Object.pm line 23
    Moose::Object::new('MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::MxRun', 'class', 'LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm', 'plugins', 'HASH(0x387f1a0)', 'parsed_args', 'MooseX::Runnable::Util::ArgParser=HASH(0x3486408)') called at /usr/local/bin/mx-run line 28
    main::run at /usr/local/bin/mx-run line 9
```

I can load the module fine from a script without error. I can also run the program just fine using the [technique found here.](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Runnable::Run)

Comment: Looks like https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=58028

Comment: That bug was patched, and besides, my module name would pass that regex causing the bug. So it turns out I actually hadn't tried issuing the command without the `.pm` extension at the end of the package name like I thought. Once I removed it, it worked fine.

Comment: You're right, that ticket should be closed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moose error messages can be hard to decipher, but this is the key piece:

> Validation failed for 'MooseX::Runnable::Invocation::RunnableClass' with value "LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm"

`LaborData::Data::DBIxTest.pm` is not a valid class name. You have to drop the `.pm`, e.g.

```
mx-run LaborData::Data::DBIxTest hi
```

---

If you're curious, valid class names are determined by Params::Util::_CLASS, which looks like [this](https://metacpan.org/source/ADAMK/Params-Util-1.07/lib/Params/Util.pm#L191):

```
sub _CLASS ($) {
        (defined $_[0] and ! ref $_[0] and $_[0] =~ m/^[^\W\d]\w*(?:::\w+)*\z/s) ? $_[0] : undef;
}
```

In other words, one or more alphanumeric characters, not beginning with a number, and optionally separated by `::`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I did run it without the `.pm` but I actually hadn't.